# Tune gbm (R caret) - grid search for get best hyperparameters

Tags: r, r-caret, gbm, hyperparameters

I made a model with caret, for example for do a manual adjust of learning rate and and trees:

```
gbmGrid <-  expand.grid(
                        n.trees = 1000,
                        interaction.depth = 10,
                        shrinkage = 0.01,
                        n.minobsinnode=1

                        )
```

But the sensitivity result metric is poor, is not so beautiful as specificity.

I think I need create a grid search ([like this](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/blog/2014/2/1/lw6har9oewknvus176q4o41alqw2ow) ) to optimize probability thresholds for class imbalances in an automatic way.

How can i do it ? Is there a link / some that guide me / someone with the knowledge like the link case of Random Forest?

Comment: I think more code and description of the data is needed or this Q may get closed for lack of clarity.